# Problema al Enviar y Recibir Datos

Tags: java, spring

estoy intentando realizar dos procesos mediante bean, mi problema radica en que no encuentro la manera que estos procesos se realizen continuamente.
El primer proceso es de envio de un objeto y el segundo proceso es la respuesta del mismo .

```
@Component
public class Proceso implements InitializingBean{
private static final String XML_SCHEMA_LOCATION = "/proceso/model/schema/proceso.xsd";
private Envio envio;
private Respuesta respuesta;

public void Proceso_envio(Proceso proceso, OutputStream outputstream) throws JAXBException{
  envio.marshal(proceso, outputstream);}

public void Proceso_respuesta(InputStream inputstream) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException{
Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
return (Proceso_respuesta) obj;}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception{
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(getClass().getResource(XML_SCHEMA_LOCATION));
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Envio.class, Respuesta.class);

this.marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
this.marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
this.marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
this.marshaller.setSchema(schema);

this.unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

this.unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
 }
```

Imagino que con el código mi pregunta se vea más clara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a añadir la palabra clave synchronized a los métodos.

Mas de una vez me ha pasado algo parecido a esto y no me hacía los procesos porque el método que recibe, intenta leer algo que no ha llegado

Al añadir esa palabra clave los metodos se sincronizan y mientras uno está haciendo una cosa el otro no va a llamarse hasta que el otro haya acabado

Te dejo el javadoc para mas info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: voy a probar tu respuesta, muchas gracias

Comment: espero más respuestas